# Generate a recovery key for a FileVault

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, filevault

When I created a FileVault encrypted partition to install OSX Yosemite, I don't think I created a recovery key. Is it possible to create a recovery key after the fact? How do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the disk until you forget the password of all users that can unlock the disk. (You might want to create another user for this purpose and store the password safely)

If you did not write the unlock key down nor used icloud storage for it, you have no way to recover or re-create the key.

Comment: How positive are about that information? The program fdesetup has a command changerecovery which says "Change or add recovery key", I'm just not 100% sure of how it works yet.

Comment: Not fully sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you correctly initialised a recovery key with:

```
fdesetup haspersonalrecoverykey
```

if the answer is:

```
false
```

then you can create a first one with:

```
fdesetup changerecovery -personal
```

which will ask for your current password:

```
Enter your password:
New personal recovery key = 'WA2P-VJ3H-14WE-Z9MT-74PQ-UTC6'
```

Next, you will have to securely store this recoverykey on an unconnected
encrypted storage with the name of your disk and user ( to avoid errors
when you will have many disks and users with time ).